# Automatic text entry dependent on text in other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, automation, conditional-statements

I have two columns of text and want to automatically enter text into the third column depending on the text in the previous two columns.  It's a risk matrix; for instance if A1 says 'Likely' and B1 says 'Minor' I need C1 to automatically say 'Medium'.  There are 9 possibilities that I need to include in the results cell as follows:

- Unlikely + Minor = Low
- Unlikely + Moderate = Low
- Possible + Minor = Low
- Likely + Minor = Medium
- Possible + Moderate = Medium
- Unlikely + Major = Medium
- Likely + Moderate = High
- Likely + Major = High
- Possible + Major = High

I've tried using `IF` but am getting bogged down with the syntax as I am not a heavy user of Excel.  I'd appreciate any help or to know that it can't be done!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (**including the code they are using**) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Máté Juhász’s table lookup approach is probably the best general solution. 
But, if we look at your risk matrix as a matrix,

```
                           B
               Minor    Moderate   Major
    Unlikely   Low      Low        Medium
A   Possible   Low      Medium     High
    Likely     Medium   High       High
```

a pattern emerges:

[image]

If we look at it numerically,

```
             B
         1   2   3
    1    1   1   2
A   2    1   2   3
    3    2   3   3
```

[image]

and then really stare at the numbers until they begin to stare back,
the pattern condenses into a formula:

```
C = INT((2*(A+B)-1)/3)
```

which leads to this solution:

```
=CHOOSE(INT((2*(MATCH(A1,{"Unlikely","Possible","Likely"},0)
               +MATCH(B1,{"Minor","Moderate","Major"},0))-1)/3), "Low", "Medium", "High")
```

Comment: I did like you said and stared at the numbers until they stared back.  Now they won't stop looking at me!  Make them stop!

Answer (score 1):

You can surely do it with nested `IF` functions but it will result a long and complicated formula. I'd suggest to create a helper range as in picture below then use `VLOOKUP` to get the desired value.

the formula in column "C": `=VLOOKUP(A1&B1,E:F,2,FALSE)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use AND and OR statements in a nested if

=IF(OR(AND(A1="possible",B1="Minor"),(AND(A1="Unlikely",OR(B1="Minor",B1="Moderate")))),"LOW",IF(OR(AND(A1="Likely",B1="Minor"),AND(A1="Possible",B1="Moderate"),AND(A1="Unlikely",B1="Major")),"MEDIUM",IF(OR(AND(A1="Likely",B1="Moderate"),AND(A1="Likely",B1="Major"),AND(A1="Possible",B1="Major")),"HIGH","")))